# new JImage: The image file does not exist

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I trying to resize image like below

```
<?php
    $file = htmlspecialchars($product->image);
    $image = new JImage($file);
    $properties = JImage::getImageFileProperties($file);
    $resizedImage = $image->resize(108, 108, true);
    //definition of mime
    $resizedImage->toFile(htmlspecialchars($product->image), $type);
?>
    <img src="<?php print $product->image ?>"/>
```

but a row 2 causes an error

> 0 The image file does not exist.

A file is exists and code

```
<img src="<?php print $product->image ?>"/>
```

shows an image(without code for resizing above).

If I trying to hardcode path to image like this

```
new JImage(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_goods-11.jpg');
```

this does not cause errors.

However, a warning message appears below

> Warning:
>   imagejpeg(http://localhost/svark/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_goods-11.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\svark\libraries\joomla\image\image.php
>   on line 985

I'm using Joomla 3.6.5 with JoomShopping 4.15.1.

Answer (score 1):

You need an absolute path for editing purpose, you cannot use http.

To use an absolute path, change this

```
new JImage(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_goods-11.jpg');
```

TO

```
new JImage(JPATH_BASE.'/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_goods-11.jpg');
```